# Remove the last character from a word in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am using CloudFormation and passing the hosted zone (i.e domain name) for e.g: domain.com. and subdomain for e.g subdomain names as variables. Now in code, I need to obtain subdomain.domain.com.

One option is to use `fn:split` but this will just help me to split but not to omit last character. Is there any way to achieve this in CloudFormation?

Comment: You want to remove dot character?

Comment: There is no elegant solution for that. Where do the subdomain and domain come from? If they are paramters, you could use them directly rather then trying to remove the dot.

Comment: I can do that but for route 53 hosted zone I need to enter with dot.
Agreed as a work around I can enter without dot and add dot manually if required.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, the easiest would be to add dot where it is needed. Removing a dot can also be implemented using, say, custom resources, but it's a drag.